# Android barcode scanner (Zxing) - does it work for UK products?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Just wondering, I'm planning to implement a barcode scanner into an Android app for my final year project at uni, but just wondering, does it fetch only US products or can I make it so it searches UK stores?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing it does is search Google, although it will search google.co.uk or google.com depending on your phone locale. So "yes", but really the answer is "whatever is in Google Shopping".